# How to pass heap parameters for non-gui distributed load test in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, heap-dump, distributed-testing

Running a distributed non-gui load test causing heap dump. Need to pass command line parameters to set heap preferences while running jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute distributed, slaves should already ready to accept requests, so you need to define it earlier.

[Running JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) recommends setting values in setenv.bat/sh

> setting the variable JVM_ARGS will override most pre-defined settings, for example
>
> ```
> JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" jmeter -t test.jmx [etc.]
> ```
>
> will override the HEAP settings in the script.
>
> To set those variables permanently, you can place them in a file called setenv.sh in the bin directory. This file will be sourced when running JMeter by calling the jmeter script. An example for bin/setenv.sh could look like:
>
> ```
> # Use a bigger heap, but a smaller metaspace, than the default
> export HEAP="-Xms1G -Xmx1G -XMaxMetaspaceSize=192m"
> ```